What's the highest starting ECL for a Small/Medium Humanoid in 3.5?
I'm making a character that gets the racial traits of a small or medium humanoid species, without also getting that humanoid's HD or LA. To keep things from getting subjective, and operating under the (admittedly flawed) assumption that higher ECL races have better racial features*, what's the Humanoid race with the highest starting ECL?
(How am I doing this? Was already looking at the Aranea monster class (Savage Species) for something else when I realized that at 5th level it also gets the racial traits of another species pretty much for free).
No templates, and while the wording of the Aranea's class feature is a little ambiguous, I'm going to say no Monstrous Humanoids either. I would, however, count an unplayable Humanoid (LA: -) with lots of RHD, even though it doesn't technically have an ECL.
*If you have a good race that doesn't have a particularly high ECL, feel free to add it in the comments below the question.

This related question covers highest RHDs for playable humanoids.

The aranea’s change shape ability is not really ambiguous—humanoid and monstrous humanoid are two separate and mutually-exclusive terms in the 3.5e rules, and the rules do not use “humanoid” to refer to both. If monstrous humanoids were an option for araneas, the ability would say “humanoid or monstrous humanoid.”

Sorry if this may be obvious, but what is ECL?

Effective Character Level (ECL) is a combination of your Character Level - which in this case is just Racial Hit Dice (this is what most monsters are made of instead of class levels) - and Level Adjustment, which is the designers saying "this race is strong enough that you need to be [X] levels behind in order to fit in with a normal party". (They were historically really bad at this, massively overpenalizing monstrous races). # of RHD + # of Class Levels + LA = ECL.

Per this related question, belgoi from Dungeon vol. 111 have 4 RHD and LA +4, for an ECL of 8th. Unlike most options at higher ECL, these are just humanoids and not monstrous humanoids.
They’re also preposterously underpowered for that ECL. They’d be underpowered at half that ECL.

The best I've found so far?
Dark Stalker (Fiend Folio)
With 3 RHD and a whopping +5 LA, starting ECL 8 is the score to beat.

Fun fact, the text description of Dark Stalkers as characters suggests that should have had an LA of +2, for an intended starting ECL of 5. IIRC this actually happened a couple of times in Fiend Folio, where the writers misunderstood how LA works with RHD (or didn't realize monster characters keep their RHD).

I'm guessing we're excluding templates in our answer, because they significantly increase the count with scalable templates like "lycanthrope".
Does "Humanoid" in your question include "Monstrous Humanoid"?
From a quick glance at the Monster Manual alone:

Doppelganger - ECL 8
Gargoyle - ECL 9

Quick glance at Monsters Manual 3:

Harssaf - ECL 10 - Monsters Manual 3 page 82
Witchknife - ECL 12 - Monsters Manual 3 page 194


No templates, and I'm going to say no Monstrous Humanoids as well. I'll edit that into the main question.

“Humanoid” does not include Monstrous Humanoid under 3.5e rules. While it’s good that the question’s been clarified to be explicit, Humanoid and Monstrous Humanoid are mutually-exclusive terms under the rules and this was never a valid answer to the question.
